# How to insert space after each character in a string MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a character string and for reporting/alignment purpose I need to insert a space after each character. Unfortunately I will have to do it in a SQL or I can write format function.

e.g. "abcd123" to be converted it to "a b c d 1 2 3 ".

Since it's for a considerable number of rows I was wondering how optimized it will be to parse each character and build a new string each time?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious to know what the reporting reasons are.

Comment: Thanks Xinus something similar first came to my mind. But what I have read is MySQL does not have that function. I came across a User defined library on a website but dont know how to use that and will that mean I need to copy the libs to customer site?

Any help you can provide about it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick & dirty mysql function which solves your problem:

```
delimiter ||
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS concat_whitespace||
CREATE FUNCTION concat_whitespace( x longtext) RETURNS longtext
LANGUAGE SQL NOT DETERMINISTIC READS SQL DATA 
BEGIN
DECLARE len INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE erg LONGTEXT;
SET len = LENGTH(x);
REPEAT
SET erg = CONCAT_WS(' ',SUBSTRING(x,len,1),erg);
SET len = len - 1;
UNTIL len < 1 END REPEAT;
return erg;
END;
||
```

Now try this:

```
Select concat_whitespace("abcd123")
```

which returns
    "a b c d 1 2 3"

This function basically loops for each character and concats a space. Direction is from end to beginning, which saves a counter variable.

I havn't done any performance test, fur sure you somehow could optimize this..

Comment: Thanks RngTng for breaking the ice for me. I think I can take it forward.

Comment: @BT.: If you were able to improve this function, I'd love to see the results.

Answer (score 2):

I would not recommend storing unnecessary spaces in SQL. This will only waste space.

How about writing a custom retrieval method that will return all strings from your DB with spaces after each character?

Comment: Yeah thanks for the advice. Actually the resultant string will not be stored into the database but will be used on a report. If I were to write a function that takes a string value as a parameter and puts the space in each of them. Can it be done?

Comment: It sure can. What language are you generating this report with?

Comment: Its a proprietary reporting tool that offers virtually no support to format/manipulate the string retrieved from database. Hence the value returned by a query has to have a space between characters.

The end report has a rigid format and alignment issues. I know it sucks cause it's a legacy system. Don't have a luxury to have the string processed by a high level language before display.

Thanks guys for the time, efforts and answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
update tablename set comment= trim(concat(substr(comment, 1,1),space(1),substr(comment, 2,1),space(1),substr(comment, 3,1),space(1),substr(comment, 4,1),space(1),substr(comment, 5,1),space(1),substr(comment, 6,1),substr(comment, 7)));
```

here comment is column name

Comment: What if the lengths are not consistent?