# Add comma between every character of a string on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to add a comma between each character of a string on mysql.

From `my_table`

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | hello |

To :

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | h,e,l,l,o |

Comment: I think you'll need to write a stored function for this, I don't think it's possible in MySQL string functions. If you're using MariaDB 10.0.5 or newer you could do it with `REGEXP_REPLACE()`.

Comment: Check out this question for info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928392/how-to-insert-space-after-each-character-in-a-string-mysql

Comment: You can use a recursive cte (if supported by MySQL.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8.0, you could try [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) function.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(name, "(.)(?!$)", "$1,")
FROM my_table
```

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/6YOIx_dR)

Answer (score 2):

Another MySQL8 REGEXP_REPLACE -

```
SELECT id, REGEXP_REPLACE(name, '(?=.)(?<=.)', ',')
FROM my_table;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/grpZMJZ9) and [regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/r/yxlXUg/1)

Since [MySQL 8.0.4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#:%7E:text=MySQL%20implements%20regular%20expression%20support%20using%20International%20Components%20for%20Unicode%20(ICU)) the regex implementation has been using [International Components for Unicode (ICU)](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/strings/regexp.html) - *patterns and behavior are based on Perl’s regular expressions*